# Lombok Usage - It doesn't serve its functionality in a unit test

Tags: spring-data, lombok

A domain object is setup as the following:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Foo {
  ...

  public Foo(...){
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

It is fine when I run a build with a set of tests. When I only run the test class, however, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.abc.myapp.Foo; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.abc.myapp.Foo
```

The project setup is with Spring Boot generated by the project generator on spring.io. And the following is the Gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.0.RC1'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-    plugin:${springBootVersion}")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
  baseName = 'spring-data-samples'
  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
   testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
   testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
```

}

And IDE is Intellij Idea.

What is missing?

Comment: Obviously the part of your setup that invoked lombok is broken in your test setup. Since we know absolutely nothing about your setup, we can't help. But maybe you want to provide some relevant information, like: How do you build your application (Build tool, IDE ...), including the relevatn configuration of plugins. How do you execute your application and how do you execute your tests. Again including relevant plugins and configuration.

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks for input. I add the project build/configuration information in my question. I don't have any plugin for the project.